# problem with updateTabItems. in R shiny with Golem

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, golem, bs4dash

I am bulding an app with golem in R .  I'm trying to change a TabItem through a button from  tabItem (acceuil) to  an other tabItem (Rating)

this is Module "Acceuil"

```
mod_Accueil_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("do"), "Click Me")
 
  )
}
    
#' Accueil Server Functions
#'
#' @noRd 
mod_Accueil_server <- function(id){
mod_Accueil_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input,output,session){
   
     ns <- session$ns
    
     observeEvent(input$do, {
      updateTabItems(session = session,inputId = "menu",selected = "Rating")
      
    })
   
  })
}
```

it seems like the mod_Acceuil dosen't recognize  the inputId and selected in the updateTabItems.
this is the app_ui part

```
sidebarMenu(id="menu", 
                tags$head(                
                menuItem("Rating", tabName = "Rating"),
                menuItem("Accueil", tabName = "Accueil")

))
tabItems(
    tabItem("Rating",mod_calcul_ui("calcul_ui_1") ),
    tabItem("Accueil",mod_Accueil_ui("Accueil_1") )
    )
```

so the problem is when i click the button "Click me" the page does not change

Comment: in the server part i call the Accueil server function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without testing: Try passing the parent's session to `updateItems`. That would require to add the parent's session to the server module:

```
mod_Accueil_server <- function(id, parent) moduleServer(id, 
    function(input,output,session) {
        ns <- session$ns
        observeEvent(input$do, {
           updateTabItems(
               session=parent,  # not the module's session
               inputId="menu",selected = "Rating"
           )
        })
    })
```

and then in the main server function:

```
server <- function(input,output,session) {
    mod_Accueil_server(id="Accueil", parent=session)
    # ...
}
```